# How to perform double contour integrals?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let's say I have an integral of the form
$$\oint\oint \frac{dz_1}{2\pi i} \frac{dz_2}{2\pi i} \frac{1}{(z_1 + n_1)(z_2 + n_2)(z_1 + z_2 + n)}$$
where $n_1,n_2,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and both the contours are of the form which go from $c-i\infty$ to $c+i\infty$ in both cases for $c\in(0,1)$ and the contour is closed to the left at infinity.

How would one evaluate the integral? What bothers me is that when $n=n_1+n_2$, we end up getting a double pole, while in other cases there seems to be a single pole. How do we take care of this?

Comment: You're trying to integrate in $\mathbb{R}^4 \simeq \mathbb{C}^2$, but the classic residue theorem is formulated for $\mathbb{C}$. The singularity at $z_2 + j$ for example is not a singular point, but an entire two-dimensional subspace (since $z_1$ is unconstrained). See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481656/multivariate-residue-theorem).

Comment: @MrArsGravis. It's an iterated integral with two integrals in $\mathbb{C}$. The residue theorem does apply here.
$$
\oint  \frac{dz_1}{2\pi i}\frac{1}{z_1+i} \left( \oint \frac{dz_2}{2\pi i} \frac{1}{(z_2 + j)(z_1+z_2+k)} \right)
$$

Comment: The choice of $i$ certainly wasn't the best choice of parameter name here.

Comment: @md2perpe what has got me bothered is that the order of integration seems to matter. If not in this case, then at least upon introducing $f(z_1)g(z_2)$ where both $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic, the order seems to matter

Comment: I've renamed the parameters, following the remark by @md2perpe.

Comment: Do you have an example where the order seems to matter?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose (perhaps a tiny bit more generally) that the contours go from $c_{1,2}-i\infty$ to $c_{1,2}+i\infty$, for $z_{1,2}$ respectively, where $c_1,c_2\in(0,1)$. The term "closed to the left at infinity" is *not a property* of such a contour, but rather a *limiting process*, when the path from $c-i\infty$ to $c+i\infty$ is replaced by the segment $[c-iR,c+iR]$ and, say, the halfcircle $|z-c|=R$ lying in $\Re z\leqslant c$, and the limit $R\to{\raise 1pt\tiny{(+)}}\infty$ is taken. [I'm using this term myself below.]

Assuming that $z_1+z_2+n$ doesn't vanish (that is, $c_1+c_2+n\neq 0$), the given double integral *is absolutely convergent*. Thus, Fubini's theorem *guarantees* that the order of integration does *not* matter. This is also confirmed by the result below (which is symmetric w.r.t. simultaneous $n_1\leftrightarrow n_2$ and $c_1\leftrightarrow c_2$).

The obvious substitutions show that our integral is $I(n_1+c_1,n_2+c_2,n+c_1+c_2)$, where $$I(a,b,c)=\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\frac{1}{(z_1+a)(z_2+b)(z_1+z_2+c)}\frac{dz_1}{2\pi i}\frac{dz_2}{2\pi i}.\qquad(a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}_{\neq 0})$$ The computation of $I(a,b,c)$ is merely a bunch of case distinctions.

To ease it, we use the 1D analogue: for $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}\setminus i\mathbb{R}$, we have $$\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\frac{1}{(z+z_1)(z+z_2)}\frac{dz}{2\pi i}=\begin{cases}1/(z_2-z_1),&\Re z_1>0\wedge\Re z_2<0\\1/(z_1-z_2),&\Re z_1<0\wedge\Re z_2>0\\\hfill 0,\hfill&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ (the proof is easy: if $\Re z_1<0$ and $\Re z_2<0$, we "close to the left" as above, getting the poles out of the contour, so the integral is $0$; *note that this works for $z_1=z_2$ too, so that the double pole is **not** an issue*; likewise, if $\Re z_1>0$ and $\Re z_2>0$, we "close to the right", and the integral is $0$ again; in the remaining cases, we go either way, computing the residue at a single *simple* pole).

Now we just proceed with iterated integration, in any order. The final result is $$I(a,b,c)=\begin{cases}1/(c-a-b)&\text{if }a,b,-c\text{ are of the same sign}\\\hfill 0\hfill&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Is it correct to first assume the contour to follow one half-circle, then throw out the half-circle part and later choose the other half-circle?

Comment: @MrArsGravis: No, it is not, and the logic of the above is different.

Comment: We have $\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}=\lim_{R\to+\infty}\int_{-iR}^{iR}$. Now we add a half of $|z|=R$ (either to the left or to the right of the imaginary axis), and obtain a *closed* contour, giving us the ability to evaluate integrals along it using the residue theorem. And *finally* we observe that integrals along the halfcircles *vanish* after $R\to+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! I agree that if we're interested in the straight line only, this seems OK. I thought OP wanted the closed contour, but maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: @MrArsGravis: This is exactly what I'm talking about in the first paragraph of the answer. The words "*... and the contour is closed to the left at infinity*" (in the question) make no sense; a contour "going from $c-i\infty$ to $c+i\infty$" simply *can't be closed*, for any reasonable meaning of "$c\pm i\infty$". But if we understand this as a *limiting process*, then - yes - we can throw a zero-in-the-limit thing out for another one. (I know this should go to the OP rather than you...)